# Saving a loop of ggplot2 boxplots as a list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a series of boxplots using **ggplot2**. A toy data-frame, OR.df, consists of 14 variables I wish to create boxplots for over factor *prop.bdlf*, grouped by *method_type*. I want to save them in a list so that I can edify them later, or print them out.

```
set.seed(24542)
OR.df <- data.frame(
  matrix(rnorm(1400, 0, 1), ncol = 14, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("Estimate.", 1:14))),
  method_type = paste0("Method", 1:5), prop.bdlf = as.factor(c(0, 3, 5, 10))
)

#Start plotting ...
my.plot <- vector(mode = "list", length = 14)
for(j in 1:14){
  title <-  gsub("Estimate.", "", colnames(OR.df)[j])
  cat("> Plotting...", paste0( "w = ", colnames(OR.df)[j]),
      "with title", title, "\n")
  p <- ggplot(  OR.df, aes(y= OR.df[ , j], x = method_type , fill = prop.bdlf) ) +
    ggtitle(paste(title, word[l], sep ="-")) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs( x = "Method Type", y  = "weight" ) +
    theme(legend.position = "right", legend.text=element_text(size = 11) ) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title="BDL Prop"))
  my.plot[[j]] <- p
} #end weight loop

multiplot( plotlist = my.plot[10:11])
```

[image: The resulting plot]

The plots are the same! Why? The data is clearly different.

```
> summary(OR.df$Estimate.10)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-1.83717 -0.66358 -0.12748 -0.09981  0.36622  2.16782 
> summary(OR.df$Estimate.11)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-2.86220 -0.67540  0.07784  0.08359  0.73410  2.82225
```

So, why is the same data being plotted in the loop? If I go inside the loop and set j = 11, the plot "p" matches exactly with the separate plot.

Thank you.

Comment: I used the `multiplot()` function from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/)

Comment: In duplicate, the second answer solved the problem. The reason is not mentioned in the duplicate, but @akrun gave one below.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that in the `y` parameter passed is the column value instead of the column name, while the `x` and `fill` are correctly passed i.e.

OR.df[,1], OR.df[,2], ..., OR.df[, 14] would be replaced with the column names as a symbol and evaluate (`!!`) it

```
my.plot <- vector(mode = "list", length = 14)
for(j in 1:14){
  title <-  gsub("Estimate.", "", colnames(OR.df)[j])
  cat("> Plotting...", paste0( "w = ", colnames(OR.df)[j]),
      "with title", title, "\n")
  p <- ggplot(OR.df, aes(y= !! rlang::sym(names(OR.df)[j]),   # change here
                x = method_type , fill = prop.bdlf) ) +
    ggtitle(paste(title, j, sep ="-")) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    labs( x = "Method Type", y  = "weight" ) +
    theme(legend.position = "right", legend.text=element_text(size = 11) ) +
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title="BDL Prop"))
  my.plot[[j]] <- p
}
```

-testing (`multiplot` from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/))

```
multiplot(plotlist = my.plot[10:11])
```

-output

[image]

Comment: I added a seed (24542) to make the example reproducible. If you could edit the answer, that would be great.  Your answer is different than the ones found on the duplicate pages -- and your explanation is helpful! The reasons for this occurrence in `ggplot2()` was not specified.

Comment: @phargart. I edited the post with new data